# Android Studio - How to implement an interface methods in all the implementing classes?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an interface which is being implemented in some 20-30 classes. I have added a new new method to this interface. 
Is there any shortcut in Android Studio to override this method in all the sub classes? Or do I need to manually go to all the classes and 
implement manually?

Comment: there is no such way available, you need to do it manually.. :)

Comment: Hello, after implementing interface, clean the project. Android Studio will list the errors in logcat and cliking it, you can directly jump to particular class. Just do ALT+ENTER, your new method of interface will be implemented..! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java 8, then there's new interface feature called "default method" you may try using:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: I'm using Java 7

Answer (score 0):

Ya, There is a way to achive such things by making your method DEFAULT inside your Interface.

For Example :

```
public interface oldInterface {

public void existingMethod();

    default public void newDefaultMethod() {

    System.out.println("New default method"

          " is added in interface");

}

}
```

The following class will compile successfully in Java JDK 8,

```
public class oldInterfaceImpl implements oldInterface {

public void existingMethod() {

    // existing implementation is here…

}
```

}

```
If you create an instance of oldInterfaceImpl:?

    oldInterfaceImpl obj = new oldInterfaceImpl ();

// print “New default method add in interface”

obj.newDefaultMethod();
```